# Is there a way to make this code run faster when constantly doing calculations on previous rows? [repost]

Tags: r, data.table

I have written code that looks like this - for id2>1, I want PRES_INVT to take the previous value in the column and add PRESCRIBED_DURATION then substract DISPENSED_DURATION, in grouping by id1 then id2. id1 is defined as the person's unique id while id2 is defined as the row number for each id1. This is a panel dataset.

```
b[, PRES_INVT := PRESCRIBED_DURATION-DISPENSED_DURATION]

b[id2>1, PRES_INVT := b[.I-1, PRES_INVT]+PRESCRIBED_DURATION-DISPENSED_DURATION, .(id1,id2)]
```

I was wondering if anyone can guide me on how I could make this run quicker?
I am working with 64M rows and the code was still running after 6 hours.

Here is the sample table:

```
id1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2) id2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5) date = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05", "2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-08","2020-01-09","2020-01-10") PRESCRIBED_DURATION = c(42,0,32,0,0,30,0,0,0,0) DISPENSED_DURATION = c(42,0,32,0,0,30,0,0,0,0) b = data.table(id1,id2,date,PRESCRIBED_DURATION,DISPENSED_DURATION)
```

Here is the expected result:

```
structure(list(id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), id2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09","2020-01-10"), PRESCRIBED_DURATION = c(42, 0, 32, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0), DISPENSED_DURATION = c(38, 0, 31, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0), PRES_INVT = c(4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd8155ead60>)
```

shift(PRES_INVT) didnot work because it seems like I cannot reference the same column when defining the same column, I keep referencing only the first row in the column so I had to look back up the rows using the index I. Additionally, I did not want to change anything for each person's row 1 (id2==1), I only want to change each person's row 2 onwards (id2>2).

Comment: Edit your original question instead of reposting without change

Comment: In your sample data, `PRESCRIBED_DURATION-DISPENSED_DURATION` is always zero and the initial `PRES_INVT` is also zero.